# Software-center crashed and problem with apt-get install -f

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center, dependencies

My software center on ubuntu 14.04 crashed. Some sources say that i have to do `sudo apt-get purge software-center`. but, when i run it there is some error, one of them is

> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
>   specify a solution).

So i try to do `apt-get -f install`. but the result is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
hplip-data python-samba
The following packages will be upgraded:
hplip-data python-samba
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7.274 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 352449 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hplip-data_3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/hplip-data_3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 135
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 135
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/hplip-data_3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, what i have to do?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy hplip-data`

Answer (score 0):

Purge the problematic packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge hplip-data 
sudo apt-get purge python-samba
```

Also, see everything is ok by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check on apt-get using :

```
sudo apt-get check
```

It will check for dependencies problems and fixn if your problem persists, try to  edit the dpkg status file manually :

`sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status` (You can use vi or nano if you want to)

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block that concern it and don't forget to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the packages in the archive

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/*
```

Yes, I'm sure. **;)**

Now run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And how said, you should remove `software-center` :\

Please reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i try to run dist-upgrade. it returns "Preparing to unpack .../hplip-data_3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ..."